# how to distinguish between "phone" and "phone cover" when searching for "phone" in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I'm trying to create the search functionality of an e-commerce application and I have different categories of products including phone and phone covers.
when I search for "phone" I would like to see products that have a category of phone not phone cover. but for some reason products with phone cover category will get a higher score.

Comment: please share your index mapping, your query, and a sample of your docs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the fields you search for and your strategy to boost the scores.

First, let's understand Elasticsearch scoring.

**Elasticsearch's _score is a ranking algorithm used to determine the relevance of search results. The score is calculated based on a combination of factors, including `term frequency`, `inverse document frequency`, and `field length normalization`.**

Let's say you have an Elasticsearch index of books with fields for "title" and "description". You want to search for books that match the query "science fiction novel".

Elasticsearch will search through the "title" and "description" fields of each book in the index and calculate a score for how well each book matches the query. The _score will be higher for books that have the words "science", "fiction", and "novel" appearing more frequently in their title and description.

**For example, suppose you have two books in your index:**

> Book 1: Title: "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy". Description: "A
> comedic science fiction novel about the adventures of an unwitting
> human and his alien friend."

> Book 2: Title: "The Great Gatsby".
> Description: "A classic American novel about the excess and decadence
> of the 1920s."

When you search for "science fiction novel", Elasticsearch will return both books, but with Book 1 ranked higher because it contains all three terms of the query in both its title and description. The _score for Book 1 would be higher than the _score for Book 2, indicating that it is a better match for the query.

Here is a good article for e-commerce tune search relevancy:
https://medium.com/quantyca/reviving-an-e-commerce-search-engine-using-elasticsearch-e540751c6d99